# Insert Ignore in Codeigniter

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

I am trying to insert a rows into the MySQL table using Codeigniter Active records.

Model Function:

```
$this->db->from('school');
$this->db->where('school_name',$cat);
$result = $this->db->get();
$count=$result->num_rows();
if($count==1):
   $data = array("flag_hide"=>"FALSE");
   $this->db->where('school_name',$cat);
   $this->db->update("school",$data);
   $cat_row=$result->first_row('array');
   $cat_id=$cat_row["school_id"];
else:
   $data=array("school_name"=>$cat);
   $this->db->ignore();
   $this->db->insert("school",$data);
   $cat_id=$this->db->insert_id();
endif;
return $cat_id;
```

The ignore() is not working.I don't know how to use ignore in Codeigniter.
Please help.

Comment: what is CI Version used in your project ??

Comment: 3.0.1 @Manishsharma

Comment: You can write a query manually `$this->db->query('INSERT IGNORE INTO table (field) VALUES (value)');`

Comment: ok let me check , by the way good question

Comment: The function `ignore()` does not exist in the `db` library (class). The comment from Alexander Popov seems to be the solution you seek.

Comment: Plz check this one https://gist.github.com/gerlv/598293